# Having py2exe include my data files (like include_package_data)

Tags: python, packaging, py2exe, setuptools, distutils

I have a Python app which includes non-Python data files in some of its subpackages. I've been using the `include_package_data` option in my `setup.py` to include all these files automatically when making distributions. It works well.

Now I'm starting to use py2exe. I expected it to see that I have `include_package_data=True` and to include all the files. But it doesn't. It puts only my Python files in the `library.zip`, so my app doesn't work.

How do I make py2exe include my data files?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ended up solving it by giving py2exe the option `skip_archive=True`. This caused it to put the Python files not in `library.zip` but simply as plain files. Then I used `data_files` to put the data files right inside the Python packages.

Answer (score 3):

`include_package_data` is a setuptools option, not a distutils one. In classic distutils, you have to specify the location of data files yourself, using the `data_files = []` directive. `py2exe` is the same. If you have many files, you can use `glob` or `os.walk` to retrieve them. See for example the [additional changes](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/MatPlotLib) (datafile additions) required to setup.py to make a module like MatPlotLib work with py2exe.

There is also a mailing list [discussion](http://objectmix.com/python/115674-py2exe-distutils-how-include-tree-files.html) that is relevant.

Comment: From what I remember, there's a problem with `data_files`: The way you specify the path to which it should install the data files is not relative to where your package is. For example, if you specify `''`, it will copy the data files to `c:\Python26\ `, which is bad. So yeah, you can specify `'Lib\site-packages\whatever'`, but then things will break if the user has installed the package in some other folder.

Is there a solution?

Comment: I have now tried it, and the problem is different than I remembered it. (Back then I was just installing with `setup.py`, and now we're doing `py2exe` so things are different.) What happens is that the files get put in the `dist` directory, alongside the `.exe`. This is bad because they should be inside the `library.zip` in their natural place inside the various Python packages.

How can I get them to be put in the `library.zip`?

Answer (score 3):

Here's what I use to get py2exe to bundle all of my files into the .zip.  Note that to get at your data files, you need to open the zip file.  py2exe won't redirect the calls for you.

```
setup(windows=[target],
      name="myappname",
      data_files = [('', ['data1.dat', 'data2.dat'])],
      options = {'py2exe': {
        "optimize": 2,
        "bundle_files": 2, # This tells py2exe to bundle everything
      }},
)
```

The full list of py2exe options is [here](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/ListOfOptions).

Comment: b-list guy answered my question! I'm honored.   But anyway, I wouldn't want to put the data files into the `.exe` file, I'd want them in the Python packages.

Comment: @cool-RR I've updated my answer with the settings to bundle everything into the .zip.

Comment: Wow, didn't know about the `bundle_files` option, thanks. Though I'm starting to like the idea of not having a zip file, so I think I'll stick with that.

Comment: Your solution does not work for me. The data files are not included in library.zip.

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to do this by overriding one of py2exe's functions, and then just inserting them into the zipfile that is created by py2exe.

Here's an example:

```
import py2exe
import zipfile

myFiles = [
    "C:/Users/Kade/Documents/ExampleFiles/example_1.doc",
    "C:/Users/Kade/Documents/ExampleFiles/example_2.dll",
    "C:/Users/Kade/Documents/ExampleFiles/example_3.obj",
    "C:/Users/Kade/Documents/ExampleFiles/example_4.H",
    ]

def better_copy_files(self, destdir):
    """Overriden so that things can be included in the library.zip."""

    #Run function as normal
    original_copy_files(self, destdir)

    #Get the zipfile's location
    if self.options.libname is not None:
        libpath = os.path.join(destdir, self.options.libname)

        #Re-open the zip file
        if self.options.compress:
            compression = zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED
        else:
            compression = zipfile.ZIP_STORED
        arc = zipfile.ZipFile(libpath, "a", compression = compression)

        #Add your items to the zipfile
        for item in myFiles:
            if self.options.verbose:
                print("Copy File %s to %s" % (item, libpath))
            arc.write(item, os.path.basename(item))
        arc.close()

#Connect overrides
original_copy_files = py2exe.runtime.Runtime.copy_files
py2exe.runtime.Runtime.copy_files = better_copy_files
```

I got the idea from [here](http://crazedmonkey.com/blog/python/pkg_resources-with-py2exe.html), but unfortunately py2exe has changed how they do things sense then. I hope this helps someone out.