# py2exe/py2app and docx don't work together

Tags: python, py2exe, docx, py2app

Installed docx on Windows 7 here:

D:\Program Files (x86)\Python27\Lib\site-packages as shown below:

[image]

Installed docx on OS X at /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/docx-0.0.2-py2.7.egg-info as shown below:
[image]

Following is the sample script (named as docx_example.py), which runs absolutely fine on the python interpreter:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
'''
This file makes an docx (Office 2007) file from scratch, showing off most of python-docx's features.

If you need to make documents from scratch, use this file as a basis for your work.

Part of Python's docx module - http://github.com/mikemaccana/python-docx
See LICENSE for licensing information.
'''
from docx import *

if __name__ == '__main__':        
    # Default set of relationshipships - these are the minimum components of a document
    relationships = relationshiplist()

    # Make a new document tree - this is the main part of a Word document
    document = newdocument()

    # This xpath location is where most interesting content lives 
    docbody = document.xpath('/w:document/w:body', namespaces=nsprefixes)[0]

    # Append two headings and a paragraph
    docbody.append(heading('''Welcome to Python's docx module''',1)  )   
    docbody.append(heading('Make and edit docx in 200 lines of pure Python',2))
    docbody.append(paragraph('The module was created when I was looking for a Python support for MS Word .doc files on PyPI and Stackoverflow. Unfortunately, the only solutions I could find used:'))

    # Add a numbered list
    for point in ['''COM automation''','''.net or Java''','''Automating OpenOffice or MS Office''']:
        docbody.append(paragraph(point,style='ListNumber'))
    docbody.append(paragraph('''For those of us who prefer something simpler, I made docx.''')) 

    docbody.append(heading('Making documents',2))
    docbody.append(paragraph('''The docx module has the following features:'''))

    # Add some bullets
    for point in ['Paragraphs','Bullets','Numbered lists','Multiple levels of headings','Tables','Document Properties']:
        docbody.append(paragraph(point,style='ListBullet'))

    docbody.append(paragraph('Tables are just lists of lists, like this:'))
    # Append a table
    docbody.append(table([['A1','A2','A3'],['B1','B2','B3'],['C1','C2','C3']]))

    docbody.append(heading('Editing documents',2))
    docbody.append(paragraph('Thanks to the awesomeness of the lxml module, we can:'))
    for point in ['Search and replace','Extract plain text of document','Add and delete items anywhere within the document']:
        docbody.append(paragraph(point,style='ListBullet'))

    # Search and replace
    print 'Searching for something in a paragraph ...',
    if search(docbody, 'the awesomeness'): print 'found it!'
    else: print 'nope.'

    print 'Searching for something in a heading ...',
    if search(docbody, '200 lines'): print 'found it!'
    else: print 'nope.'

    print 'Replacing ...',
    docbody = replace(docbody,'the awesomeness','the goshdarned awesomeness') 
    print 'done.'

    # Add a pagebreak
    docbody.append(pagebreak(type='page', orient='portrait'))

    docbody.append(heading('Ideas? Questions? Want to contribute?',2))
    docbody.append(paragraph('''Email <python.docx@librelist.com>'''))

    # Create our properties, contenttypes, and other support files
    coreprops = coreproperties(title='Python docx demo',subject='A practical example of making docx from Python',creator='Mike MacCana',keywords=['python','Office Open XML','Word'])
    appprops = appproperties()
    contenttypes = contenttypes()
    websettings = websettings()
    wordrelationships = wordrelationships(relationships)

    # Save our document
    savedocx(document,coreprops,appprops,contenttypes,websettings,wordrelationships,'docx_example.docx')
```

Following is the setup script (named as docx_setup.py) to create the standalone (.app in Mac OSX and .exe in Windows 7):

```
import sys,os

# Globals: START
main_script='docx_example'
dist_dir_main_path=os.path.abspath('./docx-bin')
compression_level=2
optimization_level=2
bundle_parameter=1
skip_archive_parameter=False
emulation_parameter=False
module_cross_reference_parameter=False
ascii_parameter=False
includes_list=['lxml.etree','lxml._elementpath','gzip']
# Globals: STOP

# Global Functions: START
def isDarwin():
    return sys.platform=='darwin'

def isLinux():
    return sys.platform=='linux2'

def isWindows():
    return os.name=='nt'
# Global Functions: STOP

if isDarwin():
    from setuptools import setup

    # Setup distribution directory: START
    dist_dir=os.path.abspath('%s/osx' %(dist_dir_main_path))
    if os.path.exists(dist_dir):
        os.system('rm -rf %s' %(dist_dir))
    os.system('mkdir -p %s' %(dist_dir))
    # Setup distribution directory: STOP

    APP = ['%s.py' %(main_script)]
    OPTIONS={'argv_emulation': False,
             'dist_dir': dist_dir,
             'includes': includes_list
            }
    print 'Creating standalone now...'
    setup(app=APP,options={'py2app': OPTIONS},setup_requires=['py2app'])
    os.system('rm -rf build')
    os.system('tar -C %s -czf %s/%s.tgz %s.app' %(dist_dir,dist_dir,main_script,main_script))
    os.system('rm -rf %s/%s.app' %(dist_dir,main_script))    
    print 'Re-distributable Standalone file(s) created at %s/%s.zip. Unzip and start using!!!' %(dist_dir,main_script)    

elif isWindows():
    from distutils.core import setup
    import py2exe

    # Setup distribution directory: START
    dist_dir=os.path.abspath('%s/win' %(dist_dir_main_path))
    if os.path.exists(dist_dir):
        os.system('rmdir /S /Q %s' %(dist_dir))
    os.system('mkdir %s' %(dist_dir))
    # Setup distribution directory: STOP

    OPTIONS={'compressed': compression_level,
             'optimize': optimization_level,
             'bundle_files': bundle_parameter,
             'dist_dir': dist_dir,
             'xref': module_cross_reference_parameter,
             'skip_archive': skip_archive_parameter,
             'ascii': ascii_parameter,
             'custom_boot_script': '',
             'includes': includes_list
            }
    print 'Creating standalone now...'
    setup(options = {'py2exe': OPTIONS},zipfile = None,windows=[{'script': '%s.py' %(main_script)}])
    print 'Re-distributable Standalone file(s) created in the following location: %s' %(dist_dir)
    os.system('rmdir /S /Q build')
```

**Now comes the real problem.**

Following is the error posted on Mac OS X console after trying to use the docx_example.app, created using the command python docx_setup.py py2app:

```
docx_example: Searching for something in a paragraph ... found it!
docx_example: Searching for something in a heading ... found it!
docx_example: Replacing ... done.
docx_example: Traceback (most recent call last):
docx_example:   File "/Users/admin/docx-bin/osx/docx_example.app/Contents/Resources/__boot__.py", line 64, in <module>
docx_example:     _run('docx_example.py')
docx_example:   File "/Users/admin/docx-bin/osx/docx_example.app/Contents/Resources/__boot__.py", line 36, in _run
docx_example:     execfile(path, globals(), globals())
docx_example:   File "/Users/admin/docx-bin/osx/docx_example.app/Contents/Resources/docx_example.py", line 75, in <module>
docx_example:     savedocx(document,coreprops,appprops,contenttypes,websettings,wordrelationships,'docx_example.docx')
docx_example:   File "docx.pyc", line 849, in savedocx
docx_example: AssertionError
docx_example: docx_example Error
docx_example Exited with code: 255
```

Following is the error posted in docx_example.exe.log file in Windows 7 after trying to use the docx_example.exe, created using the command python docx_setup.py py2exe:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "docx_example.py", line 75, in <module>
  File "docx.pyo", line 854, in savedocx
WindowsError: [Error 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'D:\\docx_example\\docx_example.exe\\template'
```

As you can see, both OS X and Windows 7 are referring to something similar here. Please help.

Comment: Not a solution, but have you tried [cx_Freeze](http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/) instead? I've had a lot of success with it (and it has Python 3 support, support for Windows, Linux and OS X).

Comment: If you open the library file that py2exe generated is the docx module present, along with it's template directory?  You should be able to open the file with any zip / archive program.

Answer (score 1):

i have found a solution

in api.py

From

```
_thisdir = os.path.split(__file__)[0]
```

To

```
_thisdir = 'C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\docx'
```

Or whatever your docx file is

Answer (score 0):

What's going on (at least for py2exe) is something similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2747860/having-py2exe-include-my-data-files-like-include-package-data).

The documentation on data_files is [here](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/data_files).

What you basically have to do is change

```
setup(options = {'py2exe': OPTIONS},zipfile = None,windows=[{'script': '%s.py' %(main_script)}])
```

to

```
data_files = [
    ('template', 'D:/Program Files (x86)/Python27/Lib/site-packages/docx-template/*'), 
]

setup(
    options={'py2exe': OPTIONS},
    zipfile=None,
    windows=[{'script': '%s.py' %(main_script)}],
    data_files=data_files
)
```

The exact place where the template files are may be wrong above, so you might need to adjust it.

But there may be several other sets of data_files you need to include.  You may want to go about retrieving them programatically with an `os.listdir` or `os.walk` type of command.

As mentioned in the other post, you will also have to change

```
bundle_parameter=1
```

to

```
bundle_parameter=2
```

at the top of the file.

Comment: Can you please post your edits to the setup code I posted above?

Comment: @user699540 I hope my new explanation gets you going down the right path. py2exe is a total PITA.

Comment: @user699540 Are you getting the same error?  Does it change anything?  As I said py2exe is a huge PITA when I'm looking at the screen myself.  Can you give me anything else?  Also, is the effort you're putting into making it natively executable w/o python worth this effort... especially on Mac, which has python installed by default?

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the entire problem by using [this](http://python-docx.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) API which is based in `python-docx`. The advantage of the API is that this one doesnt have the `savedoc` function so you will not have any other `AssertionError`.

For the `WindowsError: [Error 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'D:\\docx_example\\docx_example.exe\\template'` error you need to edit the `api.py` file of docx egg folder which is located in the Python folder of the system (in my computer: `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\python_docx-0.3.0a5-py2.7.egg\docx`)

Changing this:

```
_thisdir = os.path.split(__file__)[0]
_default_docx_path = os.path.join(_thisdir, 'templates', 'default.docx')
```

To this:

```
thisdir = os.getcwd()
_default_docx_path = os.path.join(thisdir, 'templates', 'default.docx')
```

The first one was taking the actual running program and adding it to the path to locate the `templates` folder. 
`C:\myfiles\myprogram.exe\templates\default.docx`

The solution takes only the path, not the running program.
`C:\myfiles\templates\default.docx`

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of changing some library file, I find it easier and cleaner to tell python-docx explicitly where to look for the template, i.e.:

```
document = Document('whatever/path/you/choose/to/some.docx')
```

This effectively solves the py2exe and docx path problem.