# Python's docx module giving AsserionError when .exe is created

Tags: python, py2exe, assertion, python-docx

I've a Python file titled `my_python_file.py` that makes, among other things, a `.doc` file using the `python-docx` module. The `.doc` is created perfectly and gives no problem. The problem comes when I build a `.exe` of my script and I try to make the `.doc`. An `AssertionError` problem appears.

This is my exe maker code (`exe_maker.py`):

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe, sys, os
sys.argv.append('py2exe')

setup(
    options = {'py2exe': {'bundle_files': 3, 'compressed': True, 'includes': ['lxml.etree', 'lxml._elementpath', 'gzip', 'docx']}},
    windows = [{'script': "my_python_file.py"}],
    zipfile = None,
)
```

It seems that moving the python  script to a different location produces the error.

```
  File "docx.pyc", line 1063, in savedocx
AssertionError
```

This is the `savedocx` line:

```
document = newdocument()
[...]
coreprops = coreproperties(title=title, subject=subject, creator=creator, keywords=keywords)
approps = appproperties()
contenttypes2 = contenttypes()
websettings2 = websettings()
wordrelationships2 = wordrelationships(relationships)
path_save = "C:\output"
savedocx(document, coreprops, approps, contenttypes2, websettings2, wordrelationships2, path_save)
```

The `savedox` is well writen as it works when it's not an `.exe` file.

How can I make the `docx` module work correctly? Do I've to add any other path/variable more when I make the exe?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the line that is raising the AssertionError? Also, is the code up on GitHub or somewhere I can inspect it? Not much to go on here I'm afraid. Also note that post-Word 2007 files are given a `.docx` extension rather than the old `.doc` extension. I also see that PIL or Pillow is not in the dependency list.

Comment: I added the line of the `savedoc` but as I said on the question it's not a programing problem of the `savedoc` line as it works perfectly when the `.exe` is not build. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I also added `PIL` to the `ìncludes` line but its not working either.

Comment: Sorry Borja, I don't have a clue then. Seems like a question for someone who knows about py2exe. The only thing I can think of that might be worth a try is to see if swapping in the new rewrite of python-docx and see if that works. The API is different so your .docx building code would need to be changed, but maybe if you just try a trivial three-line .docx file build and see if py2exe likes it: http://python-docx.readthedocs.org/

Comment: I've also tried that one but it's not working either. I've the same problems, works perfectly without the .EXE and gives an error if the .EXE is build. This time shows up the following error: `PackageNotFoundError: Package not found at C:\Me\workspace\MugapeGUI\dist\guiMugapeMenu.exe\docx\templates\default.docx'`

I copied the `docx\templates\` path to the current path, but it's taking the .exe as a path and it's impossible to solve. Any ideas scanny? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The entire error is: `File "Tkinter.pyc", line 1410, in __call__
  File "guiMugapeMenu.py", line 1268, in <lambda>
  File "guiMugapeMenu.py", line 1300, in guardar_planificacion_a_imprimir
  File "docx\api.pyc", line 31, in __init__
  File "docx\api.pyc", line 152, in _open
  File "docx\opc\package.pyc", line 107, in open
  File "docx\opc\pkgreader.pyc", line 31, in from_file
  File "docx\opc\phys_pkg.pyc", line 31, in __new__
PackageNotFoundError: Package not found at 'C:\Me\workspace\MugapeGUI\dist\guiMugapeMenu.exe\docx\templates\default.docx'`

Comment: Ooh, that *is* a bit interesting. One thing the two packages have in common is that they have some "package data", files that are read in like data at runtime. They are "template" documents, the default starting places when you create a new Word document with e.g. `document = Document()`. This other SO answer might be a help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2747860/having-py2exe-include-my-data-files-like-include-package-data, also a search on 'py2exe package data' seems to turn up quite a bit.

Comment: I tried by including the entire `docx` folder, where the templates are located using `data_files`: `data_files = [('template', ['C:/Python27/Lib/site-packages/python_docx-0.3.0a5-py2.7.egg/docx/*'])],` but it shows me another error: `error: can't copy 'C:Python27\Lib\site-packages\python_docx-0.3.0a5-py2.7.egg\docx\*': doesn't exist or not a regular file` . And of course, it does exist!

Comment: The main problem is that in the path to seach the `docx\templates\default.docx` is adding the name of my `.exe` as you can see in the error: `C:\Me\workspace\MugapeGUI\dist\guiMugapeMenu.exe\docx\templates\default.docx` If I could remove that `guiMugapeMenu.exe` from the path the problem should be solved, as I can copy `\docx\templates\default.docx` manually. But I dont know where I've to do that 'remove the .exe from the path'. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not familiar with py2exe behavior Borja, but from what I quickly read about it, it seems what you would want is something like this, if it can even work: `data_files = [('docx/template', ['C:/Python...2.7.egg/docx/templates/*'])]`. But it's really a py2exe question I'm afraid and I have no expertise with that package.

Comment: Thank for all your help. I tried that and it's not working either. This users has the same problem and tried the same solution, but nothing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10214105/py2exe-py2app-and-docx-dont-work-together

Comment: I finally found a solution. If you are interested, please check the answer @scanny . Have a good day and thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by edditing the `api.py` file of docx egg folder which is located in the Python folder of the system.

Changing this:

```
_thisdir = os.path.split(__file__)[0]
_default_docx_path = os.path.join(_thisdir, 'templates', 'default.docx')
```

To this:

```
thisdir = os.getcwd()
_default_docx_path = os.path.join(thisdir, 'templates', 'default.docx')
```

The first one was taking the actual running program and adding it to the path to locate the `templates` folder. 
`C:\myfiles\myprogram.exe\templates\default.docx`

The solution takes only the path, not the running program.
`C:\myfiles\templates\default.docx`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of changing some library file, I find it easier and cleaner to tell python-docx explicitly where to look for the template, i.e.:

```
document = Document('whatever/path/you/choose/to/some.docx')
```

This effectively solves the py2exe and docx path problem.