# Error while generating executable files using py2exe (python)

Tags: python, py2exe, python-docx, python-packaging

I am trying to create an executable file which is using module python-docx.

The executable files is created but this error occurs when I run the executable file.

> [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'D:\Pycharm Projects\pydocx\dist\library.zip\docx\parts\..\templates\default-footer.xml'

The normal *.py* file which I am trying to convert into a  *.exe*  works perfectly fine.

Can anyone suggest how should I resolve this

Comment: I think you'll find this has to do with the `data_files` setting in the `py2exe` configuration, something like what is mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2748026/1902513. They are not included by default perhaps. You'll need everything in that `templates/` directory to be included (so you shouldn't need to call them out one-by-one).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switched to pyinstaller and everything worked flawlessly.